# I am writing a trigger in MYSQL i want to get day of week

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am new to MYSQL. I am trying to write a trigger where if day of week is saturday or sunday it should fail.

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1 on contact
AFTER INSERT
   AS
      DECLARE @dayName VARCHAR(9);
      IF @dayName = 'Saturday' OR @dayName = 'Sunday'
      BEGIN
         RAISERROR ('data insertion is prohibited in weekends.', 16, 1);
         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
      RETURN 
END
```

I am not able to find how to get day of week in trigger. If there is any other issue in trigger you can find thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose you'll have to provide a date... or how should `dayName` receive it's value?

Comment: Using  DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE());  ?

Comment: we need to get day of week for today.. thanks

Comment: so it will be DECLARE @dayName = DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()); ? .. thanks

Comment: Be sure to read the documentation of DAYOFWEEK as it returns a number, not the actual day name...

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the table schema it is hard to answer but say that your schema is this

```
ContactTable

Id (int) | EnterStartDateTime (Datetime)

-----‐--------------------------------------
```

You would want to change the trigger to

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1 on contact AFTER INSERT 
IF DayOfWeek(NEW.EnterStartDateTime) = 1 OR DayOfWeek(NEW.EnterStartDateTime) = 7 
BEGIN 
     RAISERROR ('data insertion is prohibited in weekends.', 16, 1); 
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
END
```

Or something along those lines. This is not tested but you can look at W3 SCHOOLS for more helpful functions like these.

If you are actually using a varchar for the day column then just replace your variable with the keyword **NEW** to get the newly inserted object

References:
[W3 Resource](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayofweek-function.php)

Comment: NEW.EnterStartDateTime is variable defined in MYSQL trigger? Or Can i use DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) in that place?

Comment: No, the "NEW" keyword is. It represents the inserted record before it is put into the table. I was saying that I don't know the column names of your table so I made an example with a column name of "EnterStartDateTime"

Comment: I just want to confirm if today is saturday or sunday... how i can do that? Thanks

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayofweek-function.php

Comment: Sunday is 1 by default

Comment: Saturday is 7 by default